# EKF of robot_localization have a delay compared to GPS data

Tags: ros2, ekf, gps, ros-humble

I am using ros2 humble and the extended Kalman Filter from the robot_localization package to get both the `odom -> base_link` and `map -> odom` transform.
The first work quite well, but I am struggling a bit with the second one. I use the navsat transform node to get an odometry from the fix data, and it seems to work well, the position shown in rviz is pretty coherent.
I use a system called RTK, which gives me really accurate GPS position (we are talking centimeter level precision) and it seems also well reported in the odometry message. 
However, when I input this in my Kalman Filter, I notice a strange behavior : the robot's position is delayed compared with the gps odometry, in fact it seems that it won't move at the start of the movement, while it do when I only input my IMU and odometry to my EKF (for the `odom->base_link` transform).
I would have thought that adding a more precise measurement could only make it more precise, but in this case with navigation, it get worse from a time perspective and it is uncontrollable. I would have thought that the estimation would take the value of the GPS odometry as it's current position, and use the velocity in between two values of GPS odometry to smooth the measurement.
I tried to increase the process noise covariance, without success. 
Here is my configuration for the ekf node :

```
ekf_global:
ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0 # 30.0
    sensor_timeout: 0.05 #2.0
    two_d_mode: true
    transform_time_offset: 0.0
    transform_timeout: 0.2
    print_diagnostics: false
    debug: false
    debug_out_file: /path/to/debug/file.txt
    publish_tf: true
    publish_acceleration: false
    map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
    odom_frame: odom_combined            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
    base_link_frame: base_footprint  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
    world_frame: map           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified
    odom0: odom_combined
    odom0_config: [false, false, false,

                   false, false, true,

                   true,  true,  false, 

                   false, false, false,

                   false, false, false]
    odom0_queue_size: 1
    odom0_nodelay: false
    odom0_differential: true
    odom0_relative: false

    odom1: /odometry/gps
    odom1_config: [true, true, false,

                   false, false, false,

                   false, false, false,

                   false, false, false,

                   false, false, false]
    odom1_queue_size: 1 

    odom1_nodelay: true

    odom1_differential: false

    odom1_relative: false


    imu0: mobile_base/sensors/imu_data

    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, true,
                  false, false, false]



    imu0_nodelay: false
    imu0_differential: true
    imu0_relative: false
    imu0_queue_size: 4 #4
    imu0_pose_rejection_threshold: 0.8                 
    imu0_twist_rejection_threshold: 0.8               
    imu0_linear_acceleration_rejection_threshold: 0.8  
    imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

    use_control: false

    process_noise_covariance: [5.50,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0, #0.05

                               0.0,    3.50,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0, #0.05

                               0.0,    0.0,    0.06,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,

                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,

                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.03,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0, 

                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.15,   0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0, #0.06

                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1.35,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0, #0.025

                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     1.20,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0, #0.025

                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.04,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,

                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,

                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,

                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.2,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0, #0.02

                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1.1,    0.0,    0.0, #0.01

                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1.1,    0.0, #0.01

                               0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.015]


    initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-5, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0, #1e-9

                                  0.0,    1e-5, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0, #1e-9

                                  0.0,    0.0,    1e-9, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,

                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,

                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,

                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,

                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,

                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9, 0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,

                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9, 0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,

                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,  0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,

                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     1e-9,  0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,

                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     1e-9,  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,

                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     1e-9, 0.0,    0.0,

                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    1e-9, 0.0,

                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    1e-9]
```

If anybody know what I could try, I would be glad to hear it, and thanks for reading !

Answer (score 0):

Overall this sounds like a tuning problem. Which isn't something that we can effectively help you with online. You'll need to isolate the problem overall more effectively to provide an answerable question.

> The robot's position is delayed compared with the gps odometry, in fact it seems that it won't move at the start of the movement, while it do when I only input my IMU and odometry to my EKF (for the odom->base_link transform).

I'd pull a little at this thread and ask is your GPS data and your computer synchronized? GPSs have their own clock and if you're seeing what looks like delays that could easily be due to a lack of synchronized clocks in your system.